# What is EOSIO max block size?

Tags: blocks, single-node

What is the EOS.IO software maximum block size?
Does it even have such constant limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 Megabyte.
Block producers can change that, so it's dynamic and it doesn't need a hard fork.

Comment: Could you please give any reference of that?